# When does PSL(5,q) have order exactly divisible by a specific odd power of 5?

Tags: number-theory, group-theory

In a misguided attempt at answering [a question on divisibility of simple group orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72717/infinitely-many-simple-groups-with-conditions-on-order), I looked at $\newcommand{\PSL}{\operatorname{PSL}}v_p(|\PSL(p,q)|)$ which went smooth enough for $p=2$ and $p=3$, but which just confused me for $p=5$.

Apparently if $n=2k+1$ is odd, then there are eight residue classes mod $5^{n+1}$ such that $v_5(|\PSL(5,q)|) = n$.  The residue classes seem to have some structure, but I'm having trouble seeing what it is.

Here is the early data:

- k | residues of $q$ mod $5^{2k+2}$ such that $v_5(|\PSL(5,q)|) = 2k+1$
- 0 | 2, 3, 8, 12, 13, 17, 22, 23
- 1 | 57, 68, 193, 307, 318, 432, 557, 568
- 2 | 2057, 4193, 5182, 7318, 8307, 10443, 11432, 13568
- 3 | 32318, 45807, 123932, 188568, 202057, 266693, 344818, 358307
- 4 | 280182, 1672943, 2233307, 4186432, 5579193, 7532318, 8092682, 9485443

For number theorists, we need to solve:
$$v_5(q^2-1) + v_5(q^3-1) + v_5(q^4-1) + v_5(q^5-1) - \min(1,v_5(q-1)) = n$$ for $q \mod 5^{n+2}$ but apparently this is too many cases for me.

I'd be interested in a formula for even one of the eight classes, as I think the others will follow .  If this is trivial, I'd also be interested in hearing why the even case is so different (and erratic).